# Surrounding quoted parameter with space in the batch script argument

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I'm facing one issue when passing surrounding quoted parameter with space in the batch script argument. Here is my code and the output, please let me know what is missing.

Here is my script:

```
:mainFunction
:loop   
    ECHO key %1 and value %2
    IF NOT %1=="" (
        ECHO User has provided parameter.
        IF "%1"=="-installDir" (
            IF "%2"=="" (
                ECHO Invalid value.
                EXIT /B 0
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO Valid value.
                SHIFT
            )
        )
        REM Check other parameters and parse them.
        SHIFT
        GOTO :loop
    )
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

and here is the output (with key -installDir and value "D:\Test\New Folder"):

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\BatchPro>installer.bat -installDir="D:\Test\New Folder" -addToDesktop="true"
Folder""=="" was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\Sinha\Desktop\BatchPro>
```

So please tell me why this error is coming even after providing parameter inside double quotes.

Comment: try with `IF NOT "%~1"==""` . Mind that `=` is a delimiter in the batch files and `-installDir` and `"D:\Test\New Folder"` will be taken for two different parameters.

Comment: You should use the following syntax, `If "%~1"=="-installDir" (` and `If "%~2"=="" (`. _The `~` expands removing any surrounding doublequotes_.

Comment: @npocmaka I tried with "%~1"=="", it didn't work.

Comment: @ Gerhard Barnard It did not reach till that line where it checks for %2=="". If i'm getting correct value with %1 and %2, then why this error is coming.

Comment: @Compo If "%~1"=="-installDir" ( and If "%~2"=="" also not working. Still getting same error.

Comment: @Dams yeah, sorry, I meant as a general fact, not single variable, comment removed and answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

I took what was said in the comments and created an answer. Please give this a try:

```
:mainFunction
@echo off
:loop   
    ECHO key %1 and value %2
    IF NOT "%~1"=="" (
        ECHO User has provided parameter.
        IF "%~1"=="-installDir" (
            IF "%~2"=="" (
                ECHO Invalid value.
                EXIT /B 0
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO Valid value.
                SHIFT
            )
        )
        REM Check other parameters and parse them.
        SHIFT
        GOTO :loop
    )
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

You can run `for /?` from cmd terminal and read under the *"variable substitution*" section:

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
```